# .NET Core 2.2: xUnit Theory Inlinedata not working with enum values

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, xunit

Does anybody know how to use xUnit with "Theory" and "InlineData" with `enum` values? This here is leading to the tests not being recognized as tests and not run:

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("12h", 12, PeriodUnit.Hour)]
[InlineData("3d", 3, PeriodUnit.Day)]
[InlineData("1m", 1, PeriodUnit.Month)]
public void ShouldParsePeriod(string periodString, int value, PeriodUnit periodUnit)
{
    var period = Period.Parse(periodString);
    period.Value.Should().Be(value);
    period.PeriodUnit.Should().Be(periodUnit);
}
```

The tests work and run if I use the int values of the enum instead of the enum values.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need `[MemberData]`, `enum` values should work right out of the box. As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/enums) `enums` *are* constants:

`An enum type is a distinct value type (Value types) that declares a set of named constants.`

Code example below works for me (a `.net core 3.1` *xUnit Test Project* template):

```
public class UnitTest1
{
    public enum Foo { Bar, Baz, Qux }

    [Theory]
    [InlineData(Foo.Bar, Foo.Baz)]
    public void Test1(Foo left, Foo right)
    {
        Assert.NotEqual(left, right);
    }
}
```

Something else must be giving you troubles.

Comment: Since you accespted this answer, could you please elaborate on what was the real problem? That really interests me :)

Comment: @MikeLimaSierra: Mike, I am really very sorry, I saw your comment just right now and to be honest, I don't remember how this answer helped me at that time. I just saw that the tests are running fine, as of today, with "InlineData" and the Enum. Cheers, Ingo

Comment: "Something else must be giving you troubles." - I think there's an obscure bug in there. I'm trying to solve a case where test cases with enum values in `InlineData` won't run for some reason, either. I can copy the `enum` right on top of my test case (as shown in your minimal sample) and it will run, but when I remove that local `enum` definition again and use my actual enum (with the very same local name and constants!), the test case won't run.

Comment: Case in point: As soon as I move your `Foo` enum into another (referenced!) project (within the same solution as the test project), the test case stops working. In ReSharper's unit test sessions window, the test case will just disappear from the tree when I click "Run", and in the standard VS Test Explorer, the test case will just remain in its initial state of "Not Run", without any further explanation.

Comment: same issue here. In another file is unacceptable

Comment: In case of having the enum in a referenced project, you need to pass the data as string and convert it to an enum value, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77925902/3936440

Answer (score 5):

Attributes for `[InlineData]` need constant expressions, e.g int, bool, string etc.

Use `[MemberData]` instead if the inline is not recognizing the *enum* as a constant.

```
[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(PeriodData))]
public void ShouldParsePeriod(string periodString, int value, PeriodUnit periodUnit) {
    var period = Period.Parse(periodString);
    period.Value.Should().Be(value);
    period.PeriodUnit.Should().Be(periodUnit);
}


public static IEnumerable<object[]> PeriodData() {
    yield return new object[] { "12h", 12, PeriodUnit.Hour };
    yield return new object[] { "3d", 3, PeriodUnit.Day };
    yield return new object[] { "1m", 1, PeriodUnit.Month };
}
```

Reference [xUnit Theory: Working With InlineData, MemberData, ClassData](http://hamidmosalla.com/2017/02/25/xunit-theory-working-with-inlinedata-memberdata-classdata/)