# IEnumerable to TheoryData

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable, xunit

Is there an easy way to convert an IEnumerable to TheoryData?

For example, if I want to pass the set of enumeration options, I'm looking for something like:

```
IEnumerable<TheoryData<MyEnum>> dbEnumOptions
  = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum))
    .Cast<MyEnum>()
    .ToTheoryData(v => v);
```

In general though, this would help with getting fluent LINQ stuff into TheoryData.  Currently, we're working around this by just using MemberData, but would prefer TheoryData's better compile-time type-checking.

Comment: Extension methods aren't magic. They are just code, written by someone. You can write your own `ToTheoryData<T>` extension method that does what you want. Internally, it could create the `TheoryData<T>` object, transform each source item based on the expression you provide, add those results and then return the object.

Comment: Right, but I'd like to avoid reinventing the wheel if it's already hiding in the library somewhere, particularly on a pseudo-variadic generic like TheoryData.  It seems like creating TheoryData from a list would be a relatively common use-case.

Comment: How are you using the ``TheoryData`` so that there is compiler time type checking? ``TheoryData`` ultimately returns a set of objects (``object[]``) on each iteration so it can be used with a``ClassData`` attribute, they could still have the wrong type. ``class TestSpecificData : TheoryData<string, int>`` and ``class TestSpecificData2 : TheoryData<int, string>`` both compiled just fine when used as data in this test: ``[ClassData(typeof(TestSpecificData))]
        [ClassData(typeof(TestSpecificData2))]
        public void UnitTest1(string a, int b)`` but fail at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You can create `TheoryData<MyEnum>` and use the `Add` method to add items to your `TheoryData` like this, and then use it

Note: this this will be created for each method execution

```
public static TheoryData<MyEnum> EnumValues
{
    get
    {
        var data = new TheoryData<MyEnum>();

        foreach (MyEnum item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)).Cast<MyEnum>())
        {
            data.Add(item);
        }

        return data;
    }
}
```

and use it like this

```
[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(EnumValues))]
public void Get_Input_Success(MyEnum enumValue)
{

}
```

Comment: From .NET 5, you should use `Enum.GetValues<MyEnum>()` and no cast instead of `Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum))`. But we do not know if the asker is on (legacy) .NET Framework.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built-in that does this as far as I can see, but you can easily define your own extension method to do it:

```cs
internal static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static TheoryData<T> ToTheoryData<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {
        var result = new TheoryData<T>();
        foreach (var element in enumerable)
        {
            result.Add(element);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```cs
TheoryData<MyEnum> dbEnumOptions = Enum.GetValues<MyEnum>().ToTheoryData();
```

If you need some kind of transformation, just use `Select`:

```cs
TheoryData<string> dbEnumOptions = Enum.GetValues<MyEnum>().Select(x => x.ToString()).ToTheoryData();
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and safest way is to use the constructor accepting an `IEnumerable<T>`. With modern C# this looks like this:

```cs
public class TestClass
{
    public static readonly TheoryData<MyEnum> TestData = new(Enum.GetValues<MyEnum>());

    [Theory]
    [MemberData(nameof(TestData))]
    public void TestMethod(MyEnum value)
    {
        // Arrange, Act, Assert
    }
}
```

Be aware that `MyEnum` needs to be defined in the project where `TestClass` is defined, otherwise the test will just not run. It seems like this is a bug in xUnit or test explorer / runner. In VS you can see this because the test explorer cannot discover the tests when `MyEnum` is defined in another project.

Often the enum is defined in another project, so we need a solution for this case.

Currently, I use `TheoryData<string>` to pass the enum values as `string` to the test method and then convert this string back to the actual enum values.

```cs
public class TestClass
{
    public static readonly TheoryData<string> TestData = new(Enum.GetNames<MyEnum>());

    [Theory]
    [MemberData(nameof(TestData))]
    public void TestMethod(string value)
    {
        // Arrange
        var valueTyped = Enum.Parse<MyEnum>(value);

        // Act, Assert
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to pass enumerable theorydata; however, this involves setting up classAttribute with a declaration for an overridable GetData method.

```
public class ClassAutoMoqDataAttribute : CompositeDataAttribute
{
    public ClassAutoMoqDataAttribute(Type className)
        : base(new ClassDataAttribute(className), new AutoMoqDataAttribute())
    {
    }
    
    public override IEnumerable<object[]> GetData(MethodInfo testMethod)
    {
        if (testMethod == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(testMethod));
        }
        var theoryAttribute = Attributes.FirstOrDefault();
        var data = theoryAttribute.GetData(testMethod);

        var autoDataAttribute = Attributes.ElementAt(1);
        if (autoDataAttribute == null)
        {
            yield break;
        }

        foreach (var datum in data)
        {
            var autoData = autoDataAttribute.GetData(testMethod).ToArray()[0];

            for (var i = 0; i < datum.Length; i++)
            {
                autoData[i] = datum[i];
            }

            yield return autoData;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no need for a custom attribute.

Comment: above solution would work for broader use cases like passing automoq dependencies and theory data together.

Comment: This isn't an AutoMoq question at all